# Using regular expressions on a list that has been converted to a string

Tags: python, regex, string, list

Take the following code:

```
>>>foo = ['abcdefgdfsrf1\tword\tfdsaerg32543','2343221d2\tfds\tss']
>>>print re.findall('(\d+)\s+(\w+)\s',str(foo))
[]
```

The regular expression isn't matching correctly because the single quotes surrounding each element of the list are interfering throwing up the quote matching for the entire string. What is the most pythonic way to alter this code so that it matches

```
1\tword\t
```

and

```
\tfds\t
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `str(foo)` is creating a representation of `foo`:

```
>>> str(foo)
"['abcdefgdfsrf1\\tword\\tfdsaerg32543', '2343221d2\\tfds\\tss']"
```

so it will escape `'\t'`, while you want the literal value.

Either join it (with a space):

```
>>> re.findall('(\d+)\s+(\w+)\s',' '.join(foo))
[('1', 'word'), ('32543', '2343221d2')]
```

or join with a non-space char:

```
>>> re.findall('(\d+)\s+(\w+)\s','x'.join(foo))
[('1', 'word'), ('2', 'fds')]
```

or iterate:

```
>>> [re.findall('(\d+)\s+(\w+)\s', str) for str in foo]
[[('1', 'word')], [('2', 'fds')]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you just use list comprehension?

```
>>> [re.findall('(\d+)\s+(\w+)\s', f) for f in foo]
[[('1', 'word')], [('2', 'fds')]]
```